# Would it be wise to package OpenERP for the PyPI or just personal use?

Tags: odoo, pypi, software-packaging

Recently, I've wanted to deploy OpenERP and also, recently, I learned about Heroku.

I thought about how to deploy OpenERP on Heroku and it came to me that there's no python package for OpenERP.

So I thought about learning how to create python packages and then package up OpenERP for my personal use on GitHub or Launchpad (because OpenERP uses Launchpad and bazaar) and then, if it is useful, submit it to PyPI.

But, first, I'll check <strike>with the rest of the world.</strike> here for some advice.

Would you recommend me to take this route?

Would it be beneficial to the OpenERP community?

Would it be a wise method of deployment, through a python package?

What are the reasons that [the official python packages on PyPI have been abandoned](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openerp-web/5.0.6)?

Answer (score 1):

OpenERP already has packages and bundles for different O/Ses available.  I would advise against creating one specifically for PyPI.

If you create one, please, please commit to maintaining it.  If you don't, it too will be abandoned.